# PuttyConnection Manager - How to change number of password retries?

Tags: putty

In Putty Connection manager, there is a feature to 'Enable Login Macro' i.e. we specify the user and password, which it uses to automatically login-into a remote box. If you clicking the highlighted checkbox, then you can specify user/pass in the next screen.

[image: putty configuration scree]

It works fine, but I would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of retires. Preferably, i only want it to automatically try once, and then abort. Currently, I see it tries for 3 times.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the daemon side or changing the Putty client software as suggested in my answer below?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for your answer. The unix box is not under my control so i can't change any daemon side setting. I understand that the SSH daemon is asking to enter the password again if it's wrong for upto 3 times. But can we anyhow change connectionManager to just supply the password once and leave the console for manual entry if asked for second time(which happens when the password is wrong). I am looking to stop retrying as there is a feature that locks the account if the password entered is incorrect.

Comment: I realize it would probably be easier if there was a way of configuring Putty to do what you want but it doesn't appear like there is. You really might take a look at the Putty source code and get a sense of what would be involved in hard coding in such a feature. Might be more work than it is worth, on the other hand it might be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Putty does not currently have an option for ConnectoinAttempts like its OpenSSH SSH client counterpart. The Putty source code is available at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html and could potentially be used to add this option. Also if you have control of the ssh server that you're logging into you could set the MaxAuthTries assuming it has this option. The OpenSSH daemon for instance does.

Answer (score 1):

From a security standpoint I would stop using PuttyConnectionManager it is not being developed anymore. I would recommend using [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/) which has a direct import feature from PuttyConnectionManager.

To answer your question further. Any setting regarding password attempts is not going to be in Putty its going to be in the SSH daemon on the other end which is enforcing the security to the machine. Look to the OpenSSH config file for information on password attempts.

And if you need autologin fuctionality like connection manager look into [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) instead of PuTTY. Its a fork of PuTTY that allows for scripts and expect logins. I use both at work and they work great!

Comment: Hi Solignis, Thanks for your answer. Could you please go through my comment on the question.